# A method to get Directory size returns different results

Tags: java, android, file, directory, size

I'm trying to get the size of a folder on Android. The problems are:

1. Each time the function returns something different.
2. It doesn't scan all files.

Can someone tell me why?

```
private long dirSize(File dir) {
    long result = 0;
    File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        // Recursive call if it's a directory
        if(fileList[i].isDirectory()) {
            result += dirSize(fileList [i]);
        } else {
            // Sum the file size in bytes
            result += fileList[i].length();
        }
    }
    return result/1024/1024; // return the file size
}
```

I got this function from another thread. How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the division at the end. Each subfolder is being rounded to nearest MB, and added to the size of the current folder in bytes. Return bytes and handle conversion in the caller.

Comment: Running the same code should return the same value, even if it's being calculated in a wrong way... @Omar should verify if something changes inside the Android while doing the operation

Comment: @Omar: verify that @developmental has pointed the problem taht occurs because you're calling the method recursivally. If it was called once, it could have worked...